# Wild card url interception in Grails using Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to secure any url starting with /admin with a wild card. All my admin actions start with admin and then the entity name as mentioned below.

/adminPerson/create
/adminPerson/show
/adminDepartment/create

etc

so I want all url staring with /admin to have at-least ROLE_ADMIN something like mentioned below

grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/admin**':    ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
]

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I think that this should work

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [ '/admin*/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'] ]
```

I believe that '**' is a shortcut for any directory path, but doesn't also replace partial words, so you need both wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [ '/admin/**': ['ROLE_ADMIN'] ]
```

with the trailing forward-slash before the asterisks?